# Is it good to move from Asp.Net MVC to sharepoint Apps?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sharepoint, sharepoint-apps

I am little bit confused now a days. I have one year of experience in .Net MVC. I have done one whole project. My key skills are MVC4,LINQ,EF,Jquery,WCF. I am about to finish this project. In my current company they are pushing to Sharepoint apps. I am very new to sharepoint environment and I dont have basic knowledge also. Since I am good in javascript and jquery they are pushing me to Sharepoint apps because sharepoint apps will utilize most of the client scripts. I am confused because without knowing basics of sharepoint is it good practice to move for sharepoint 2013 or 2016 apps? I would like to have some suggestions on this. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client side scripting are gaining lot of traction these days

with CSOM and REST api in SharePoint, you can completely avoid server side coding and complete an entire project using just Javascript and jQuery.

Also you can use all the frameworks like, Angular, bootstrap that you use in any normal web application development

SharePoint will not be too alien for a .Net developer. You can easily relate and learn stuff. Like instead of a webservice call you can call rest api and get results etc

So don't worry about moving to SharePoint/Office 365. You can use [StackExchange dedicated for SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) and you can use it for your future queries

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: I can see lot of stuffs like workflows,timerjobs,info paths etc where i have no knowledge in these areas. App latest sharepoint technology(if i am not wrong) and without studying basics of sharepoint is it sounds good to jump directly into apps?